# How to discover which value occurs the most in a HashMap?

Tags: java, string, dictionary, hashmap

```
Map<String,String> votes = new HashMap<String,String>
votes.put("Henk","School");
votes.put("Elise","School");
votes.put("Jan","Work");
votes.put("Mert","Party");
```

How can I retrieve the value that most a occur in the `HashMap` above, in this case that would be "School". I would appreciate the most efficient and clear method to approach.

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried so far? How does your code look like and what particular part gives you problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler solution is to just look at the values.

```
public static <E> E mostFrequentElement(Iterable<E> iterable) {
    Map<E, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<>();
    E mostFreq = null;
    int mostFreqCount = -1;
    for (E e : iterable) {
        Integer count = freqMap.get(e);
        freqMap.put(e, count = (count == null ? 1 : count+1));
        // maintain the most frequent in a single pass.
        if (count > mostFreqCount) {
            mostFreq = e;
            mostFreqCount = count;
        }
    }
    return mostFreq;
}
```

and for a Map you can do

```
V v = mostFrequentElement(map.values());
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, this one fits the best for my usage.
I also (trying to) make a method for returning the freqMap.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be:

- Construct a new `HashMap` that has a *String* `key` and an `int` value.
- For each `value` of your current `HashMap`:

  - Add the value as the `key` in the new `HashMap` and the value as 1 if it's the first time you're inserting it.
  - Otherwise, increment the `value` by one for the current `key`.
- Now iterate on the newly created *map* and retrieve the *key* that has the maximum *value*.

---

For your current map:

```
votes.put("Henk","School");
votes.put("Elise","School");
votes.put("Jan","Work");
votes.put("Mert","Party");
```

You'll first insert `School` as a key, with value 1. Then you face `School` again, so you increment the *value* by 1, having a count of 2. Now you insert `Work` with *value* 1, and `Party` with value 1 as well.

After iterating on the map, you'll get `School` with the highest *value*. And that's what you want!

Comment: Okay, I've worked out your solution, but I'm not sure if this is the best way out there. http://pastebin.com/zJFBsRiJ

Comment: @user2803086 You can do this in a single pass. See my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just using the API :

```
        Map<String,String> votes = new HashMap<String,String>();
        votes.put("Henk","School");
        votes.put("Elise","School");
        votes.put("Jan","Work");
        votes.put("Mert","Party");

        Collection<String> c = votes.values();
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(c);

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(c);
        Iterator<String> i = set.iterator();
        String valueMax = "";
        int max = 0;
        while(i.hasNext()){
            String s = i.next();
            int frequence = Collections.frequency(l, s);
            if(frequence > max){
                max = frequence;
                valueMax = s;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(valueMax+": "+max);
```

Output :

```
School: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you want -

```
/**
 * Get the most frequent value present in a map.
 * 
 * @param map
 *          The map to search.
 * @return The most frequent value in the map (or null).
 */
public static <K, V> V getMostFrequentValue(
    Map<K, V> map) {
  // Make sure we have an entry.
  if (map != null && map.size() > 0) {
    // the entryset from our input.
    Set<Entry<K, V>> entries = map.entrySet();

    // we need a map to hold the count.
    Map<V, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<V, Integer>();
    // iterate the entries.
    for (Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
      // get the value.
      V value = entry.getValue();

      if (countMap.containsKey(value)) {
        // if we've seen it before increment the previous
        // value.
        countMap.put(value, countMap.get(value) + 1);
      } else {
        // otherwise, store 1.
        countMap.put(value, 1);
      }
    }
    // A holder for the maximum.
    V maxV = null;
    for (Entry<V, Integer> count : countMap.entrySet()) {
      if (maxV == null) {
        maxV = count.getKey();
        continue;
      }
      if (count.getValue() > countMap.get(maxV)) {
        maxV = count.getKey();
      }
    }
    return maxV;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I would iterate over the entrySet() so you don't have to look up the key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation of Maroun pseudocode. Try,

```
   Map<String, String> votes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    votes.put("Henk", "School");
    votes.put("Elise", "School");
    votes.put("Jan", "Work");
    votes.put("Mert", "Party");
    //Define a countMap with String as value, Integer for count
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : votes.entrySet()) {
        if (countMap.containsKey(entry.getValue())) {
            countMap.put(entry.getValue(), countMap.get(entry.getValue()) + 1);
        } else {
            countMap.put(entry.getValue(), 1);
        }
    }
    // Got the number of maximum occuarance
   Integer maxNum = Collections.max(countMap.values());

    String result = "";
     // Iterate to search the result.
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : countMap.entrySet()) {
        if(maxNum==entry.getValue()){
            result=entry.getKey();
        }

    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `put()` and `remove()` of the `HashMap` class and create your custom one that also controls for the number of objects added. Like so:

```
public class MyHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

private HashMap<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

@Override
public V put(K key, V value) {
    Integer count = countMap.get(value);
    if (count != null) {
        countMap.put((String) value, ++count);
    } else {
        countMap.put((String) value, new Integer(1));
    }


    return super.put(key, value);
}

@Override
public V remove(Object key) {
    String countKey = (String) get(key);
    Integer  count = countMap.get(countKey);
    if (count != null) {
        countMap.put(countKey, --count);
    }

    return super.remove(key);
}

public Integer getCount(Object value) {
    return countMap.get((String)value);
}

}
```

This way you don't have to loop over the elements of your `HashMap` to count them. Instead, after you add them:

```
Map<String,String> votes = new MyHashMap<String,String>
votes.put("Henk","School");
votes.put("Elise","School");
votes.put("Jan","Work");
votes.put("Mert","Party");
```

You could just get the count for each as:

```
Integer schoolCount = votes.getCount("School");
```